# Mutual inclusion of header files causes problems

Tags: c++, header, include

I have two header files which include each other mutually.
Since that created errors, I did what this site suggested and removed the includes, made one of the instances a pointer, and used forward declaration.

However, other errors occurred, which I do not know the source of, or fix to.
Much thanks given in Advance.

Code dump inc.

----------------team.h------------------

```
#ifndef TEAM_H
#define TEAM_H

#include <exception>
#include "avl.h"
#include "pair.h"

class Team {
private:

    class Mutant; //Forward Declaration

    int team_ID;
    Avl<int, Mutant>* team_mutants_by_ID;
    Avl<Pair<int, int>, Mutant>* team_mutants_by_power;
    int team_most_powerful;

public:
    // C'tor
    Team(int new_team_ID);

    // D'tor
    ~Team();

    // Returns the team's mutant tree that is ID sorted.
    Avl<int, Mutant>* GetTeamMutantsByID();

    // Returns the team's mutant tree that is sorted by power.
    Avl<Pair<int, int>, Mutant>* GetTeamMutantsByPower();

}; // Team

#endif
```

----------team.cpp-------------

```
#include "team.h"

const int EMPTY = -1;

// C'tor
Team::Team(int new_team_ID)
 {
    team_ID = new_team_ID;
    team_mutants_by_ID = new Avl<int, Mutant>();
    team_mutants_by_power = new Avl<Pair<int, int>, Mutant>();
    if (!team_mutants_by_ID || !team_mutants_by_power) {
        delete team_mutants_by_ID;
        delete team_mutants_by_power;
        throw AVL_ALLOCATION_ERROR();
    }
    team_most_powerful = EMPTY;
}

// D'tor
Team::~Team() {
    delete team_mutants_by_ID;
    delete team_mutants_by_power;
}

// Returns the team's mutant tree that is ID sorted.
Avl<int, Mutant>* Team::GetTeamMutantsByID() {
    return team_mutants_by_ID;
}

// Returns the team's mutant tree that is sorted by power.
Avl<Pair<int, int>, Mutant>* Team::GetTeamMutantsByPower() {
    return team_mutants_by_power;
}
```

----------mutant.h--------------

```
#ifndef MUTANT_H
#define MUTANT_H

#include <iostream>

class Mutant {
private:
    class Team; // forward declaration

    int student_ID;
    int grade;
    int power;
    Team* team;

public:
    // C'tor
    Mutant(int student_ID, int grade, int power);

    // Default C'tor (for ghost)
    Mutant();

    // D'tor
    ~Mutant();

    // Returns a pointer to the team the mutant belongs to
    // If the mutants does not belong to a team - returns NULL
    Team* GetTeam();

}; // Mutant

#endif
```

----------mutant.cpp--------------

```
#include "mutant.h"

const int EMPTY = -1;
// C'tor
Mutant::Mutant(int student_ID, int grade, int power) : 
student_ID(student_ID), grade(grade), power(power), team(NULL) {
 }

// Default C'tor (for ghost)
Mutant::Mutant() : student_ID(EMPTY), grade(EMPTY), power(EMPTY), team(NULL)     
{
};

// D'tor - Default is enough
Mutant::~Mutant() {
}
}

// Returns a pointer to the team the mutant belongs to
// If the mutants does not belong to a team - returns NULL
Team* Mutant::GetTeam() {
    return team;
}
```

The errors are:
identifier "Team" is undefined (mutant.cpp)

declaration is incompatible with "Mutant::Team *Mutant::GetTeam()" (mutant.cpp)

int *Mutant::GetTeam(void):overloaded function differs only by return type from Mutant::Team *Mutant::GetTeam(void) (mutant.cpp)

There are similar error in team.cpp

I can include additional information if needed.
thanks is advance.

Comment: You need to include both headers in the implementation. The compiler needs to know what they are when you actually use them. Forward declaration doesn't help there.

Comment: That is excatly what I did originally, though it created errors as well.
Plus, answers to similar questions on this site said to only use forward declaration.

Should I try to use just includes, without forward declaration?

Comment: You need forward declaration in the *headers* but the *implementation* needs to have all the headers for all the classes you use. Now you're only including one but not the other.

Comment: Have you tried placing the forward references outside of the classes?

Comment: That actually solved it Mike.
Thank you very very much

Answer (score 0):

When the compiler tries to compile `Team* Mutant::GetTeam()` it sees `Team` as belonging to the global scope.  However, `Team` does not belong to the global scope, because the only place where it has been defined, as far as the compiler can tell while compiling `Mutant.cpp`, is within `Mutant`, as a forward reference.  So, `Mutant::Team* Mutant::GetTeam()` would have perhaps worked, though it would probably cause problems later, because `Team` is not really a nested class within `Mutant`.  Placing the forward reference to `Team` *outside* of class `Mutant` will probably work.

However, it would be best to `#include "team.h"` from within `mutant.h` and remove the forward declaration of `Team` in `Mutant`.

If that gives you errors, that would be the subject of a different stackoverflow question.